# Display problem on listView with xamarinForms

Tags: xaml, listview, xamarin.forms

this is my XAML source code:

```
<ScrollView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                <ListView x:Name="listViewm" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="1">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding x}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E9EDF2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="x" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E9EDF2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="y" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E9EDF2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding y}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E9EDF2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="z" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E9EDF2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding z}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#E9EDF2" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" Margin="1"></Label>
                                </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
            </ScrollView>
```

I couldn't fix the display. Here is the list displayed at runtime. Is there a solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fN2H.png)

Thanks

---

Comment: A ListView has built in scrolling, so you don’t need a ScrollView.  And you may need to define a RowHeight or a Height for the Grid

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set the **HasUnevenRows** Property:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewm" ItemsSource="{Binding MySource}" HasUnevenRows="True">
```

For more info, you could refer to [ListView appearance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/customizing-list-appearance#row-height).

Hope it works.

Comment: Other suggestions: 1. You may use CollectionView instead as it aims to provide a more flexible, and performant alternative to ListView.

Comment: You could also refer to this : [ListView.HasUnevenRows Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.listview.hasunevenrows?view=net-maui-7.0)

Comment: @Naifar Sirine May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.